# Pivot table with one row and four columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
 -- Pivot table with one row and four columns

SELECT 'Values' tValues, 
    ID,Name,ValueID,Value FROM (

        Select ID,Name,ValueID,Value FROM Table WHERE OptionID = 1000000

    ) AS SourceTable 

    PIVOT ( 

        COUNT(tValues)
        FOR tValues IN ( ID,Attribute,ValueID,Value ) 

    ) AS PivotTable;
```

I'm going off the example at Microsoft.com: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

But there are a few things about Pivot i don't really understand, so don't be surprised when you see it in the code above, such as `COUNT(tValues)`, I have no idea what this is for, by judging from the example on microsoft, it seems to be always some sort of numeric value, so i figured i'd try it to see if it would return something, but all it returns is an error. Anyhow, if someone out there can share why this query doesn't work, and possibly explain what the numeric value above the `FOR` is used for?

The `Table` containts an x amount of rows, with four columns, so it looks like this:

```
 ID  |  Name   |  ValueID  |  Value

 100 |  Color  |  10000    |  Black
 101 |  Size   |  10005    |  Large
```

The output should be like this:

```
 Name_100  |  Color   |  Name_101  |  Size  |

 10000     |  Black   |  10005     |  Large |
```

Comment: Can you show YOUR table, sample data and desired results? Can you also explain what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: @Aaron: The `Table` is a list of an X number of row results with 4 columns, the entire query doesn't work.  Can Pivot even handle this?

Comment: I have no idea. Which is why I asked for more details about what you're trying to accomplish. Can you show your table structure (`CREATE TABLE`), sample data, and what you want the output of the query to look like? Otherwise I have no idea what "this" is that pivot is expected to handle.

Comment: ok i added the table info above.

Comment: Ok, now can you describe what makes these two rows related? What if you had a third row with `102, Gender, 10006, Male`?

Comment: Ok,  `Table WHERE OptionID = 1000000` as modified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe.

**This will only work if the name column is unique**. If not then you might want to append an id on it.

So first some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblValues
    (
        ID INT,
        Name VARCHAR(100),
        ValueID INT, 
        Value VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO tblValues
VALUES
    (100,'Color',10000,'Black'),
    (101,'Size',10005,'Large')
```

Then you need to get the columns to pivot on:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        'Name_'+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Name,
        'Name_'+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Sort,
        tbl.ID
    FROM
        tblValues AS tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.Name,
        'Value_'+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Sort,
        tbl.ID
    FROM
        tblValues AS tbl
)
SELECT
    @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(Name),
                 QUOTENAME(Name))
FROM
    CTE
ORDER BY
    CTE.ID,
    CTE.Sort
```

Then declaring and executing the dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ''Name_''+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS pivotName,
        CAST(tbl.ValueID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS name
    FROM
        tblValues AS tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.Name AS pivotName,
        tbl.Value AS name
    FROM
        tblValues AS tbl
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(name)
    FOR pivotName IN ('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Then in my case I will drop the table I have created

```
DROP TABLE tblValues
```

**Edit**

Or in you case it should be something like this:

First the columns:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        'Name_'+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Name,
        'Name_'+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Sort,
        tbl.ID
    FROM
        [Table] AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.OptionID = 1000000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.Name,
        'Value_'+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Sort,
        tbl.ID
    FROM
        [Table] AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.OptionID = 1000000
)
SELECT
    @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(Name),
                 QUOTENAME(Name))
FROM
    CTE
ORDER BY
    CTE.ID,
    CTE.Sort
```

Then the dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ''Name_''+CAST(tbl.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS pivotName,
        CAST(tbl.ValueID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS name
    FROM
        [Table] AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.OptionID = 1000000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.Name AS pivotName,
        tbl.Value AS name
    FROM
        [Table] AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.OptionID = 1000000
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(name)
    FOR pivotName IN ('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

You do not need to create the table or drop the table. That was just because I did not have your table in my database and that if someone else want's to run the example.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Is creating the table `tblValues` necessary, when the original table already has these values in it? (as shown in the `SELECT` statement in the question?)

Comment: I updated the answer. If you are fin with the answer you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Pivot tables with a variable number of columns, then I'd suggest using something along the lines of;

```
   DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(4000)
   DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)
   SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
            '],[' + Name
                       FROM    Table
                       ORDER BY '],[' + Name
                       FOR XML PATH('')
                     ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

   SET @query =
   'SELECT * FROM
   (
        SELECT col1, col2, col3, whateverColYourInterestedIn, Name, Value
        FROM Table
   )t
   PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Name
   IN ('+@cols+')) AS pvt'

   EXECUTE (@query)
```

That is probably not quite right, but it should hopefully be a starting point for you.

For more info, check out links such as [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx) or [this](http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/using-sql-server-20052008-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns-dynamic-pivot/).

Comment: This is what I would've suggested, but your query needs a bit of cleaning up. You have a missing single-quote in your SELECT DISTINCT and doing an ORDER BY in a sub-query is a no-no - SQL Server should actually moan about that. :)

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've added the missing quote. There is no ORDER BY in a sub query, it is used in the parameter I pass to STUFF. It is how all the examples I've seen for building dynamic column lists, and I've used it successfully myself. I agree that the code might not work, but hopefully it'll give the OP some ideas, and the associated links will help them put the rest together and get their query working.

Comment: I was actually referring to the ORDER BY in the query you pass to STUFF. I've had SQL Server moan about that several times and the best solution I could garner was to put the SELECT in a CTE with a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY...) hack to get the data ordered and then just select the relevant columns from the CTE in the STUFF. Hope that makes sense... :P I upvoted your answer as I believe it's the most dynamic implementation. You could try calling sp_ExecuteSQL to make sure the query path gets cached as well...